# Android Default Video Camera Intent Opens Image Camera

Tags: java, android, android-intent, camera, video-camera

I am trying to open the android default video camera from my app, using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

But on my two phones (Samsung Note 2, and Google Pixel), it opens the image camera instead. I have this permission in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
```

Any ideas what causes this issue?
I've also requested the permission at runtime.

Comment: [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Media/VideoRecordIntent) that uses `ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` works fine on a Pixel.

Comment: Tried some things from the app but it's still not working. I'm also using the uses-feature thing, but that isn't changing anything

Comment: I just copied the code for the intent from the sample app into my app and it still isn't working

Comment: I don't know why you keep getting answers involving permissions.  You **do not need camera permissions to record a video if you are using a third part app**.  The only thing you may need is the WRITE_EXTERNAL permission to actually save the file.

Comment: Other than this, I just did the `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` intent on my HTC M9.  It seems to work appropriately.  It opened the camcorder.  One thing to note is that when using third party apps, you are forced to go with their implementation.  They may not simply open up to the camcorder when they capture this Intent.

Answer (score 0):

Add follow permission CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT and CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT

Answer (score -1):

You must add next code. Devices have Android 6.0 or later.

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 2);
    }
```

If your the app has the permission for use the STORAGE we open the STORAGE.

If your the app doesn't have permission for use STORAGE, we open system-dialog.
Result from the dialog you can see in the onRequestPermissionsResult. (You must override it on your Activity).

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
        @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == 2) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

I think you must extract next lines to the private method.

```
private void takePhoto() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
}
```

For more information see : https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I've requested the permission and all already, but it still doesn't work unfortunately. The camera app starts fine... But for some reason it starts the image camera rather than the video camera

Comment: Add follow permissions:

Comment: CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT

Comment: Add follow permission CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT and CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT

Comment: Maybe next your problem will be permission to file system. @Userrrrrrrrr

Comment: That was my issue, I needed to add 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: Yes, but use must and it to the real time permissions.

Comment: Yes, but use must and it to the real time permissions.

Comment: Yes, but use must and it to the real time permissions. And maybe you need and READ_EXSTERNAL_STOREG permission for read this file. @Userrrrrrrrr And can you like me answer.

Comment: Would you mind writing the STORAGE answer as an answer rather than a comment, so that I can accept that?

Answer (score -1):

Android 6.0 and later requieres to ask permissions at run time. Read the official doc here: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

I hope it helps.